# SVG g element height with css transition

Tags: css, animation, svg, transition

I am stuck with an issue. my goal is to create a blinking eye in svg. I created the graphic converted into svg. Now i planned to put a css animation on it so it looks like its blinking. I spent lot of time on it but not able to solve the issue.

my approach to achieve this effect is to change its g element height with css transition so it will looks like blinking but when i put css on it it just disappear :( below is the css code I used:

```
#svg_7 path{
    transform:scale(0, -1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0, -1);
}
```

**svg code**

```
<g id="svg_7">
 <path id="svg_8" d="m35.99502,49.21692c-11.88306,0 -22.25696,5.59302 -27.80701,13.90399c5.55103,8.31104 15.92505,13.90302 27.80701,13.90302c11.88306,0 22.25696,-5.59198 27.80896,-13.90302c-5.55299,-8.31097 -15.92701,-13.90399 -27.80896,-13.90399z" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#fa5400" fill="transparent" />
 <circle id="svg_9" r="9.83801" cy="63.12191" cx="35.995" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#fa5400" fill="transparent" />
```

Main purpose is to create a blinking eye that keeps blinking after every few seconds. please do suggest me a solution. even we can use js/jquery if required.

**[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kaxmiller/0tu0um8q/)**

thanks in advance 
Kax

Comment: You can't do it with a transition...you would have to use keyframe animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact to have the closest effect (to reality) of blinking eye, I think you have to redesign the eye. Such as we need to animate the upper eyelid only (not both). Also the inner pupil should be covered by the eye lid. Doing so is not easy, at least I feel like that it can be done more easily with CSS than with SVG. However the time of shutting the eye lid is short, we can just animate both the eyelid and the inner pupil. Scaling down the vertical size of both to nearly 0 should do the job. However we can notice that the `stroke-width` becomes thinner at such a small scaling (may create some visible dashed lines instead of a solid one). So we also have to animate (increase) the `stroke-width`. Here is the CSS code (please run it in webkit-based browsers, it should work for all browsers):

```
#svg_7 path{   
   -webkit-transform-origin:50%;    
   -webkit-animation:blink 3s infinite alternate;
}
#svg_9 {
 -webkit-transform-origin:50%;    
 -webkit-animation:coreblink 3s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0%, 96% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    stroke-width:1.4434px;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,0.05);
    stroke-width:6px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes coreblink {
  0%, 96% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);        
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,0.05);        
  }
}
```

Note that, if you increase the `animation-duration` (it's `3s` in the demo), you should also increase the key percentage (it's `96%` in the demo) so that the time of shutting the eye lid is not considerably large. I know this is not perfect (as what I said before), but it's at least acceptable in some use case and hope you are satisfied with it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0tu0um8q/1/).

**UPDATE**: If you want to save the SVG code into a file, you should also ship the CSS code (used to animate the SVG) along with the SVG file by using `<style>` tag like this:

```
<svg width="99" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>
  #svg_7 path{   
   -webkit-transform-origin:50%;    
   -webkit-animation:blink 3s infinite alternate;
  }
  #svg_9 {
   -webkit-transform-origin:50%;    
   -webkit-animation:coreblink 3s infinite alternate;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%, 96% {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
      stroke-width:1.4434px;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1,0.05);
      stroke-width:6px;
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes coreblink {
    0%, 96% {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);        
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1,0.05);        
    }
  }
</style>

<g id="svg_1">
<rect id="svg_2" height="71.991" width="71.99" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#ffffff" fill="transparent" y="0.71191" x="26.195"/>
<line id="svg_3" y2="0.71191" x2="26.195" y1="27.12591" x1="0" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#ffffff" fill="transparent"/>
<line id="svg_4" y2="72.70391" x2="26.195" y1="99.11691" x1="0" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#ffffff" fill="transparent"/>
<rect id="svg_5" height="71.991" width="71.992" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#ffffff" fill="#000000" y="27.12491" x="0"/>
<g id="svg_6">
<g id="svg_7">
<path id="svg_8" d="m35.99502,49.21692c-11.88306,0 -22.25696,5.59302 -27.80701,13.90399c5.55103,8.31104 15.92505,13.90302 27.80701,13.90302c11.88306,0 22.25696,-5.59198 27.80896,-13.90302c-5.55299,-8.31097 -15.92701,-13.90399 -27.80896,-13.90399z" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#fa5400" fill="transparent">        
 </path>
 <circle id="svg_9" r="9.83801" cy="63.12191" cx="35.995" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#fa5400" fill="transparent" />
</g>
</g>
<polygon id="svg_10" points="98.1849594116211,72.70391845703125 71.9919662475586,99.116943359375 71.9919662475586,27.12591552734375 98.1849594116211,0.7119140923023224 " stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.4434" stroke="#ffffff" fill="transparent"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Another approach is try using pure SVG animate. However I find it hard to have an equivalent of SVG animation to CSS animation.

Comment: Thanks - it works great - but its not working with firefox. I added -moz- but still don't work. if you can suggest something for this it would be perfect. thanks again for your help

Comment: @KaxMiller not sure why FireFox always sucks when I solve a problem. Looks like `transform-origin: 50%` does not work expectedly in FireFox, even the `transform-origin:50% 50%`. It may just happen with SVG elements (`path`, `circle`). However using absolute unit  does work. You can try a workaround by using the absolute vertical offset (equal to the `cy` of the circle) for the second argument of `transform-origin`. Here is the updated demo working in FireFox http://jsfiddle.net/0tu0um8q/2/

Comment: works amazingly great - love you - it does have a last problem. when i load it via img tag in html it doesn't blink but if i load it via object tag it starts blinking ? now i don't have any idea how to make it responsive if i use object. any hack i can do with img tag or if i can make it responsive with object tag ? thanks again for your great help.

Comment: @KaxMiller could you post the demo link which loads SVG into an `object`? Not sure how it could blink because the `animation` code is done in CSS. I'm trying converting the CSS animation to pure SVG animation and see if it works for `img`.

Comment: yeah sure http://homepage1.qbxlab.com/ - you will find that svg in 4th section. animation working fine but i am facing issues with responsive now - if i can use img there it can be easily work with all screens sizes but i don't have any idea about object. if you know something about doing responsive with object i don't have issues with that too

Comment: @KaxMiller you said it started blinking when you used `object` tag, but I've tried your demo and looks like it does not blink at all. In fact you have to embed the CSS code into your SVG file (see my update about how). Also I'm don't quite understand what you mean by *responsive* here. If you mean *interactive*, yes using `object` is the only way, `img` can just render a static view of the SVG.

Comment: Its correct that images can't be interactive but they can have non-interactive SMIL/CSS animations. I.e. they don't just need to be static views.

Comment: @RobertLongson I meant static here is non-interactive. Of course the animation runs OK when loading SVG file with `img`.

Comment: thanks king, actually i was talking about flexible images so i can set its width and height according to media queries. but now I embeded svg code directly into my html file and now it looks perfect. thanks again for your great help. you are really a helpful guy. take care